# Regex for " last, first" names in r

Tags: regex, string, stringr

I am trying to extract the names from a list of documents I have. Name are always the first occurrence of the last, first pattern.

I am trying the following regex with stringr but it does not work ^[A-Z][a-z]+,\s[A-Z][a-z]+$
I believe this is because the pattern before the regex is not constant throughout the documents. Please see the example below.

```r
library(stringr)
m = c("   name: aaaaaa, bbbbbb  age: 25" , "age 34   person: aaaa, bbbb", " location: A  name 
 aaaa, bbbbbbb", "aaaaa, bbbb")

str_extract(m, "^[A-Z][a-z]+,\\s[A-Z][a-z]+$")

# I tried to add a white space before and after the beginning of the pattern 
# but still not working:

str_extract(m, "^\\s[A-Z][a-z]+,\\s[A-Z][a-z]+$\\s")
```

The expected output is the list of names:
aaaaaa, bbbbbb
aaaa, bbbb
aaaa, bbbbbbb
aaaaa, bbbb

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Comment: sorry. the expected output is the list of name. I edited the question. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
# Base example
m = c("   name: aaaaaa, bbbbbb  age: 25" ,
      "age 34   person: aaaa, bbbb",
      " location: A  name aaaa, bbbbbbb")


# This function implement the solution
extract_lastfirst <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(`"{stringr} is required"` = requireNamespace("stringr"))

  stringr::str_extract(x, "\\w+, \\w+") # This line solve the problem
}
extract_lastfirst(m)
#> [1] "aaaaaa, bbbbbb" "aaaa, bbbb"     "aaaa, bbbbbbb"

# In the text there is a mention to "the first occurrence of", so try
# the solution with an example the have a "second" occurrence.
n <- c("name: aa, bb wrong: cc, dd")
extract_lastfirst(n)
#> [1] "aa, bb"




# formal tests for the solution ---------------------------------------
# (no output means test passed)

library(testthat)

testthat::test_that("goal achieved", {
  expected_out_m <- c("aaaaaa, bbbbbb", "aaaa, bbbb", "aaaa, bbbbbbb")
  expect_equal(extract_lastfirst(m), expected_out_m)
})

testthat::test_that("multiple occurrences", {
  expected_out_n <- c("aa, bb")
  expect_equal(extract_lastfirst(n), expected_out_n)
})
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS          
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/Rome                 
#>  date     2020-09-02                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  backports     1.1.9   2020-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr         3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  devtools      2.3.1   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  processx      3.4.3   2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.3.4   2020-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringi       1.4.6   2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  testthat    * 2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xfun          0.16    2020-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#> 
#> [1] /home/cl/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
#> [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#> [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#> [4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am not familiar with the package (testthat). would you please provide some explanation when you have a chance?

Comment: that is used only to test the answer, ie to use the `test_that()` function. You can ignore them all for your solution, I would only provide a formal check for the correctness what I purpose. Anyway, you can find information at https://testthat.r-lib.org/ (maybe looking at the "Articles" tab too).

Comment: I have edited my answer separating solution and tests (and adding some comments)

Comment: thanks for the details and the teaching on this package.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't seem to be exactly right. Try using `[A-Za-z]+,\s[A-Za-z]+` instead and see if that makes a difference. The caret in the beginning of your statement only will match strings where the pattern begins at the start of the line, and the dollar sign at the end will only match patterns which end at the very end of the line. I also combined the `A-Z` and `a-z` groups into one and removed an unnecessary backslash. It might be helpful in the future to test your regexes with something like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) which can save a lot of pain with repeatedly running the program.

Comment: I tried my regex on another website called regex101 but the website you sent looks more helpful.  thank you for the website and for the detailed explanation. the regex you sent gives the output I am looking for.